# One more LUL and I'm out

Tags: code-golf, string

## Challenge description

On some channels on a popular streaming site [twitch.tv](https://www.twitch.tv) a common message people tend to spam in chats to bait people into spamming "LUL" is

```
One more LUL and I'm out
```

[LUL](http://files.gamebanana.com/img/ico/sprays/57822c19e1ad1.png) is a popular emote used to express that something funny happened on stream.

Soon dank memes showed their potential and a parody of the copy-pasta ensued:

```
One more "One more LUL and I'm out" and I'm out
```

Which is the same message nested in itself. Given a non-negative integer `N`, output the LUL-pasta nested `N` times in itself following the pattern below.

Standard [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) rules apply, the shortest code in bytes wins.

## Sample input / output

```
0: One more LUL and I'm out
1: One more "One more LUL and I'm out" and I'm out
2: One more "One more "One more LUL and I'm out" and I'm out" and I'm out
...
7: One more "One more "One more "One more "One more "One more "One more "One more LUL and I'm out" and I'm out" and I'm out" and I'm out" and I'm out" and I'm out" and I'm out" and I'm out
```

## Notes

- Leading/trailing newlines are allowed
- Capitalization must be preserved
- Your code may be a full program or a function
- Instead of printing, you may return a string or its equivalent in your language of choice
- You may index from `1` instead of `0`

Comment: can I add `"` in the start and end too?

Comment: [Very similar](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/60475/45941) (Task 5)

Comment: @Rod: No, you cannot.

Comment: The title of this challenge is very awkward for Dutch speakers...

Comment: @Pakk But it's true. I see a LUL, and I'm outta here...

Comment: This can be extended to YOLO: `You Only YOLO once --> YOYOLOO. You Only YOYOLOO Once --> YOYOYOLOOO`, etc.

Comment: Shouldn't the start be `One more "LUL" and I'm out`?

Comment: Since I'm bored, here's a Perl-compatible regex that can match any string that could possibly be produced by the programs that are valid entries to this challenge: https://regex101.com/r/7s0CRl/1

Comment: [Nice challenge!](http://i.imgur.com/Divi9yo.png?1)

Comment: Can it be even more impressive, and follow "standard" English style by alternating “” and ‘’ ??

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn Twitch emotes only work when their names are surrounded by nothing or whitespace, so `"LUL"` wouldn't render the LUL emote. Something like `" LUL "` would, though.

Answer (score 29):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 56 bytes

```python
lambda x:('"One more '*x+'LUL'+' and I\'m out"'*x)[1:-1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#S7ON@Z@TmJuUkqhQYaWhruSfl6qQm1@UqqCuVaGt7hPqo66trpCYl6LgGaOeq5BfWqIElNCMNrTSNYz9X1CUmVeikKaRmVdQWqKhqfnfGAA)
It is 1-indexed

Comment: I assume the `[1:-1]` at the end trims the double quotes at the start and end?

Comment: @Nzall Precisely

Comment: For x=0 this gives 'U', but should give "One more LUL and I'm out".

Comment: @Wolfram It is 1-indexed, added this info to the answer

Answer (score 20):

## JavaScript, <s>57</s> <s>56</s> <s>54</s> 52 bytes

```js
f=q=>`One more ${q?`"${f(q-1)}"`:"LUL"} and I'm out`
```

Test Snippet:

```js
f=q=>`One more ${q?`"${f(q-1)}"`:"LUL"} and I'm out`
```

```html
<input type=number min=0 oninput=o.textContent=f(+this.value)>

<p id=o>
```

For some reason the snack snippet is being buggy when the input is `0`, but this works otherwise. Call it like `f(4)`.

#### Explanation

```js
f=q=>                      //declares a function f with argument q
`One more ... and I'm out` //hardcoded string
 ${q?`"${f(q-1)}"`:"LUL"}  // does recursion based on q
                           // if q is true, ie not 0, recurse
                           // else return "LUL"
```

Comment: First off `input` is an invalid HTML attribute, might wanna remove that. Secondly, it's because it takes the input as a string, not a number. So `"0"` is truthy while `0` is falsy. Easiest way to handle that is to put a `+` in front of `this.value` when you're passing it.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Thanks, I don't know why I have an extra `input` field :)

Comment: Nice, I probably would've tried using `.replace`.

Comment: Stack overflows when number is negative.

Comment: @programmer500 The input number is given to be non-negative so that is not a problem

Comment: I know, just wanted to point that out.

Answer (score 11):

## Befunge, 91 bytes

```
&:00p10p>"tuo m'I dna "1v
09p00-1<^g09p01-1_v#:g0<<vg
>>00g:#^_$>:#,_@  >$"LUL">" erom enO"
```

[Try it online!](http://befunge.tryitonline.net/#code=JjowMHAxMHA+InR1byBtJ0kgZG5hICIxdgowOXAwMC0xPF5nMDlwMDEtMV92IzpnMDw8dmcKPj4wMGc6I15fJD46IyxfQCAgPiQiTFVMIj4iIGVyb20gZW5PIg&input=Nw)

This is a breakdown of the source code with the various component parts highlighted.

[image: Source code with execution paths highlighted]

[image: *] We start by reading the repeat count *N*, and storing two duplicates of it in memory.
[image: *] We then countdown the first *N*, pushing multiple copies of " and I'm out" onto the stack in reverse. Each additional copy is separated from the one before with a quote. The quote is generated with the sequence `90g` (basically reading a copy from the first line of the source), since that's the shortest way to do so.
[image: *] Once this first loop is complete, we push "LUL" onto the stack (technically this is in reverse, but it obviously makes no difference when it's a palindrome).
[image: *] Then we have another loop, wrapping across the right border, over to the left of playfield, and then back again. This time we're counting down the second *N*, pushing multiple copies of "One more " onto the stack (again in reverse). And again, each additional copy is separated from the one before with a quote.
[image: *] Once the second loop is complete, the entire phrase is now on the stack (in reverse), so we simply need to write it out.

Comment: Nice use of get to push a `"`. Thanks for the explanation

Answer (score 6):

## C++, 118 + 16 = 134 bytes

```
auto L(int x){std::string k="One more LUL and I'm out",r=k;for(int i=0;i++<x;)r.replace(i*10-1,3,'"'+k+'"');return r;}
```

`#include<string>` - +16

replaces "LUL" to the whole string N times.

Anyone has better golfs?

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/cpp-gcc#TY/BboMwDIbveQqLHYDBaKveGuBeKdJOPEBG3M4DnCokUqeqz84CO2wXy/5kf/q9vBD3YzAI9ewd8bUVf4RsZKinVujgLaiM2MM9f8zenE6/6zA0yTsjTNYhqE6BZgPndAIbfFK6ZpAX67Y7avaSiqK@y9xVDm@j7jGj18P@7VAeyzRJi6GINZcOfXAMTj5ht/OfCJfAvSfLYtVMmjjLxUPAOnVKCtji9MTQtv9BTAB1HVN3Kl@bjSKbUUbvN84laPiw2xNfdsAqCg2iqcRzWY4/)

Massive thanks to **Kritixi Lithos** and **hvd**, for, uh, Massive help.

Comment: @Kritixi Now it has a snippet.

Comment: [This](https://tio.run/nexus/cpp-gcc#RY5Ba4QwEIXv@RVDetCguIU9Rr0XhJ78AakZ26lmsiQRtiz7223cLvQyvDfD@@btL8TTulmENqZA/NmL/w35vEPjerHFfAI2DuPFTAgxWS3@AjCUxAmu6vb0SyffGcH5gDCMAxi28FY48FuSdegWPfvwiFD3qqm9aqoqFZqAlzWjy9DMxLaUOSpVfa4LWVRLlafSAdMWGIK@w@mUvhDmjadEnsWBc4a4VOIm4HDjoAVMxND3T53/Q9vmuuOgDoFsV51BPxhrMPDhH@2//YJNJlhE24j7vp9/AQ) is shorter. And I think you might need to include the `<string>` import statement into the bytecount, not sure

Comment: Also you can change the `for(int i=0;i<x;i++)` to `for(int i=0;i++<x;)`

Comment: Additionally, `r.find("L")` is shorter than `r.find("LOL")` by 2 bytes :)

Comment: Recursive version: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/cpp-gcc#PY7BasMwEETv@opBOdTCaULpUY7vAUFPvuWiWtuiOFoFSwaHkG935Tb0tO@xwzAbz/1lcoTGx5RHsqEVU/L8DbaB0tX2hJSdXjb/wRIr/1b8XZjKc8as7k8fDtJ0Rmr/Vc2qyEnK2lTz65uqV9Yj5WlkyA8mhDgSZD3UEpYdji8BccpSP5a1M1jPlRJ3gdU6owV6z2jbJ5comqYM6IxagdhdNPb7G6UtLD7j755zHGhXGhyR24nH8v4D "C++ (gcc) – TIO Nexus")  Also you can use the header and footer on TIO for additional stuff, and then only count your code in the byte count.

Comment: Also you may be able to use `'"'` (single double single) instead of `"\""` in the above code

Comment: I am using single double single already.

Comment: You don't need to find `r.find("L")` when you can calculate it from `i` (`i*10-1`)

Comment: @hvd I know, but r.find("L") was more efficient for me.

Comment: @MatthewRoh Efficient in what way? `r.find("L")` is 11 characters, `i*10-1` is 6. This is code golf, so shorter is better, right?

Comment: Good point. @hvd

Comment: Also, the return type can be `auto` instead of `string` to save two more characters. And I *think* you need to either include `using namespace std;` in your character count, or write `std::string`, but I'm not sure on that.

Comment: Changing `,r=k` to `;auto r=k` wasn't necessary, that part was valid even with `std::string`. Your link no longer works since your demo program now also needs `std::cin`/`std::cout`/`std::endl` :)

Comment: I found a short version that uses recurrsion. http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/107654/23417

Comment: @BrainStone I wont copy that. Reasons? 1. I dont want to copy others answers. 2. I dont like recursions, Its very inefficient

Answer (score 6):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>30</s> 29 bytes

```
…LULIF“"One€£ ÿ€ƒ I'm€Ä"“}}¦¨
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@/@oYZlPqI@n26OGOUr@eamPmtYcWqxweD@QPjZJwVM9F8g43KIElK2tPbTs0Ir//40B)

Different string-types doesn't seem to mix well, so for some reason I need to end the loop twice.

Answer (score 5):

## Javascript (ES6), 68 Bytes

```
f=(x,y="LUL")=>~x?f(--x,`"One more ${y} and I'm out"`):y.slice(1,-1)
```

Call like `f(n)`.

You can also call it like `f(n, "LUL")` and replace LUL with any word you wish.

Comment: Since the question asks for just "LUL", you could probably eliminate the flexibility of changing the text and golf out some bytes. Nice solution anyway, +1

Comment: @FarhanAnam I thought this was a good starting post that I would then edit, but after I posted I saw someone had posted a better answer and no matter how hard I tried to golf it I always ended up on their answer. So I thought I should just leave it here with the flexibility so that someone has some fun with it.

Answer (score 5):

## [V](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), <s>39</s> 37 bytes

Two bytes with the help of @KritixiLithos for coming up with the substitution method

```
iOne more LUL and I'm outÀñÓLUL/"."
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/v#@5/pn5eqkJtflKrgE@qjkJiXouCpnquQX1oifbjh8MbDk4Gi@kpCekr///83AwA)

Hexdump:

```
00000000: 694f 6e65 206d 6f72 6520 4c55 4c20 616e  iOne more LUL an
00000010: 6420 4927 6d20 6f75 741b c0f1 d34c 554c  d I'm out....LUL
00000020: 2f22 122e 22                             /".."
```

Comment: It is LUL and not LOL ;)

Answer (score 4):

## Java, <strike>79</strike> 77 bytes

Golfed:

```java
String f(int l){return"One more "+(l<1?"LUL":'"'+f(l-1)+'"')+" and I'm out";}
```

Ungolfed, with test:

```java
public class OneMoreLulAndImOut {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    OneMoreLulAndImOut obj = new OneMoreLulAndImOut();
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i) {
      System.out.println(Integer.toString(i) + ": " + obj.f(i));
    }
  }

  String f(int l) {
    return "One more " + (l < 1 ? "LUL" : '"' + f(l - 1) + '"') + " and I'm out";
  }    
}
```

Program output:

```
0: One more LUL and I'm out
1: One more "One more LUL and I'm out" and I'm out
2: One more "One more "One more LUL and I'm out" and I'm out" and I'm out
3: One more "One more "One more "One more LUL and I'm out" and I'm out" and I'm out" and I'm out
4: One more "One more "One more "One more "One more LUL and I'm out" and I'm out" and I'm out" and I'm out" and I'm out
5: One more "One more "One more "One more "One more "One more LUL and I'm out" and I'm out" and I'm out" and I'm out" and I'm out" and I'm out
6: One more "One more "One more "One more "One more "One more "One more LUL and I'm out" and I'm out" and I'm out" and I'm out" and I'm out" and I'm out" and I'm out
7: One more "One more "One more "One more "One more "One more "One more "One more LUL and I'm out" and I'm out" and I'm out" and I'm out" and I'm out" and I'm out" and I'm out" and I'm out
```

Comment: You can change both `"\""` to `'"'` (single chars) to save 2 bytes.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen thanks, I knew there was something I missed.

Answer (score 3):

## Python, 79 bytes

I just wanted to do a recursive solution, even though it's longer than other answers.

```python
x='"One more %s and I\'m out"'
f=lambda n,s=x:n and f(n-1,s%x)or(s%"LUL")[1:-1]
```

[**Try it online**](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#@19hq67kn5eqkJtflKqgWqyQmJei4BmjnquQX1qipM6VZpuTmJuUkqiQp1NsW2GVB5ZP08jTNdQpVq3QzC/SKFZV8gn1UdKMNrTSNYz9X1CUmVcCVGGgyQVjGiKYRgimueZ/AA)

Answer (score 3):

### C#, 125 bytes

```
n=>{string f="One more {0} and I'm out",s=f;for(int i=0;i++<n;)s=string.Format(s,$"\"{f}\"");return string.Format(s,"LUL");};
```

Comment: I wonder if you can use [string interpolation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn961160.aspx) instead of `Format`...

Comment: Change `string` to `var` to save two bytes.

Comment: @devRicher Can't because I'm declaring 2 variables

Comment: @Bob I'm already using it, not sure if I can use it elsewhere

Comment: Whoops, I didn't notice, sorry.

Comment: @Bob On my other answer I tried using one inside another and have struggled to get it to work though so if I manage to get that to happen I can use the same logic here

Answer (score 3):

### C#, <s>119</s> <s>85</s> 71 bytes

```
string m(int n)=>$"One more {(n<1?"LUL":$"\"{m(--n)}\"")} and I'm out";
```

*Saved 14 bytes thanks to @Luc*

Comment: Looks like it works (via LINQPad). Nice. Nested interped strings does sound a bit iffy, but it looks like it chokes on the ternary first.

Comment: @Bob the problem I'm having trying to get it to work is because of the quotes, or at least that is what I think is causing it so I can't seem to remove the first `string.Format` and nest them

Comment: How about $"One more {(n<1?"LUL":$"\"{m(--n)}\"")} and I'm out"

Comment: @Luc did you try that? Cos I'm sure I did something similar and it didn't work. On my phone right now so can't test

Comment: You can in any case replace string.Format with + to get 73 chars:

Comment: string m2(int n)=>"One more "+(n<1?"LUL":$"\"{m(--n)}\"")+" and I'm out";

Comment: Yes you can nest. But you have to add (parentheses) around the ternary to do it. So Luc's is good.

Answer (score 3):

## Mathematica, <s>69</s> 68 bytes

*Thanks to Martin Ender for saving 1 hard-to-find byte!*

```
""<>Nest[{q="\"",{"One more ",#," and I'm out"},q}&,"LUL",#+1][[2]]&
```

Unnamed function taking a nonnegative integer argument and returning a string. `Nest` applies a function repeatedly to an initial argument; in this case, the function is to surround its argument by the appropriate words and quotation marks. We start from `"LUL"` and iterate `N+1` times; that results in unwanted quotation marks enclosing the entire phrase, but `[[2]]` keeps only the stuff between them. At the end, `""<>` turns the resulting heavily nested list into a single string.

Previous submission:

```
""<>Nest[{o,q="\"",#,q,a}&,{o="One more ","LUL",a=" and I'm out"},#]&
```

Comment: Managed to shave off a byte by starting from `LUL`: `""<>Nest[{q="\"",{"One more ",#," and I'm out"},q}&,"LUL",#+1][[2]]&`

Comment: Aha! `[[2]]`! That's how to get around those first undesired quotes :D

Answer (score 3):

## C, <strike>140</strike> 111 bytes

My first attempt at a golfing question..
Golfed:

```
#define F printf(
#define P 1&&putchar(34)
int a=0;void q(n){a=a?a:n,n?n>0?F"One more "),n-P:n?n+P,F" and I'm out"):0:F"LUL"),n+a?q(n-1):0;}
```

I have come to realise is the wrong output since q(0) just gives LUL.
The next attempt:

```
#define o(Q) O(Q,n?34:0);
#define O printf
void q(int n){o("One more %c")n?q(n-1):O("LUL"),o("%c and I’m out")}
```

Example program (tested with GCC on OSX):

```
#define o(Q) O(Q,n?34:0);
#define O printf
void q(int n) {o("One more %c")n?q(n-1):O("LUL"),o("%c and I’m out")}

int main() {
    q(0),putchar('\n');
    q(1),putchar('\n');
    q(2),putchar('\n');
    q(3),putchar('\n');

    return 0;
}
```

Gives output

```
One more LUL and I’m out
One more "One more LUL and I’m out" and I’m out
One more "One more "One more LUL and I’m out" and I’m out" and I’m out
One more "One more "One more "One more LUL and I’m out" and I’m out" and I’m out" and I’m out
```

Comment: [104 bytes](https://tio.run/##dc09CoNAEAXgfk8xTBBnQEGTTgvrgCAW6WzEn8TCUVetRMg1cr1cZLMkpAp55feGeZV/rSpjDnXTdtLAQDlnlHuSYIEYIXKsvl0Go@5kadVEwttAmFnsB92AMyNLYtkPOcoI00uK7NkLZ4ZSajg/748ehnVB3o19AX3ZCTFsCmwmCtgb16W6lZrcQly7@fHwjx//@OnH34VullULBLHazQs "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

### R, <strike>100 97</strike> 92 bytes

*"One more recursive function and I'm out"*

```
f=function(n)paste("One more",`if`(n<1,"LUL",paste0('"',f(n-1),'"')),"and I'm out");cat(f(scan()))
```

Edit: Turns out that a non-recursive approach is slightly shorter:

```
x="One more ";y=" and I'm out";cat(x,rep(c('"',x),n<-scan()),"LUL",rep(c(y,'"'),n),y,sep="")
```

Answer (score 2):

### [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 51 bytes

```
.+
$*00LUL1$&$*
0
"One more 
1
 and I'm out"
^"|"$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/retina#U9VwT/ivp82lomVg4BPqY6iipqLFZcCl5J@XqpCbX5SqwGXIpZCYl6LgqZ6rkF9aosQVp1SjpML1/78BUMaIy5jLhMsUAA)

Answer (score 2):

### R, 97 bytes

```
function(n){s="One more LUL and I'm out";while(n){s=sub("LUL",paste0('"',s,'"'),s);n=n-1};cat(s)}
```

Ungolfed:

```
function(n) {
  s = "One more LUL and I'm out";
  while(n) {
    s = sub("LUL", paste0('"', s, '"'), s);
    n = n - 1
  };
  cat(s)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell), <s>72</s> 67 bytes

```powershell
"$('"One more '*($c=1+"$args"))LUL$(' and I''m out"'*$c)".Trim('"')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/powershell#@6@koqGu5J@XqpCbX5SqoK6loZJsa6itpJJYlF6spKnpE@oDVKCQmJei4KmunquQX1qipK6lkqyppBdSlJkL1Kuu@f//fyMA)

Comment: `"$('"One more '*($c=1+"$args"))LUL$(' and I''m out"'*$c)".Trim('"')` shaved 5 by using a trim() instead of a join to skip the end `"`'s

Comment: @ConnorLSW nice! good call, thank you

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 39 bytes

*Thank you @ETHproductions for helping.*

```
`"O Ú `p°U +"LUL"+` d I'm t"`pU)s1J
```

[Try it here!](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.3&code=YCJPmiDakCBgcLBVICsiTFVMIitgIIRkIEknbSCMdCJgcFUpczFK&input=Nw==)

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby, 51 bytes

One-indexed. [Try it online](https://repl.it/FOl9)

```
->n{['One more ']*n*?"+'LUL'+[" and I'm out"]*n*?"}
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Go](https://go.dev), <s>104</s> 82 bytes

```go
func f(n int)string{if n<0{return"LUL"}
return`One more "`+f(n-1)+`" and I'm out`}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=LY1BCsIwFET3OcUnGxNqpQUXovUAQkER3CfUpnw0PyUmq9KTuCmCh_Ao3sZq3cwwi_fm_mjc8Gp1ddFNDVYjMbSt82HBjQ38GYNJV--jiVSBEQRIQd6CR2o6NEBF1vk6RE-8PJW8Z9NQexpdztfAVTJSaS4TxUHTGXYzCy4G1f_Ny5_5-yskdMw4D7jeZhss8jGSpGOH8SxcSeDcCJSS9ezPDsPUHw)

- -22 bytes by @Steffan: string concat instead of `Sprintf`

Comment: -22 bytes: [you don't need `Sprintf`](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=LY1BCsIwFET3OcUnGxNqpQUXovUAQkER3CfUpnw0PyUmq9KTuCmCh_Ao3sZq3cwwi_fm_mjc8Gp1ddFNDVYjMbSt82HBjQ38GYNJV--jiVSBEQRIQd6CR2o6NEBF1vk6RE-8PJW8Z9NQexpdztfAVTJSaS4TxUHTGXYzCy4G1f_Ny5_5-yskdMw4D7jeZhss8jGSpGOH8SxcSeDcCJSS9ezPDsPUHw).

Comment: The output is incorrect: `LUL` should not have quotes around it.

Answer (score 1):

### Lua, 101 bytes

```
i,f,g='"One more ',' and I\'m out"',io.read()+1 print((i:rep(g).."LUL"..f:rep(g)):sub(2,g*24-(g-2)))
```

Obvious string attempt. Repeats `"One more` and `and I'm out"` exactly input + 1 times, with a `LUL` inbetween, then removes first and last quote.

Answer (score 1):

## Stacked, 54 bytes

```
('"One more ' ' and I''m out"')*'LUL'join'^.|.$'εrepl
```

[Try it here!](https://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/stacked/stacked.html) Example usage of "function":

```
1
('"One more ' ' and I''m out"')*'LUL'join'^.|.$'εrepl
out
```

---

One for 56 bytes:

```
@n'One more LUL and I''m out':@o['LUL' '"'o'"'+ +repl]n*
```

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, <s>69</s> 66 bytes

Note: uses IBM-850 encoding

```
for($o=LUL;~$argn--;$d=~¦)$o="One more $d$o$d and I'm out";echo$o;
```

Run like this:

```
echo 2 | php -nR 'for($o=LUL;~$argn--;$d=~¦)$o="One more $d$o$d and I'"'"'m out";echo$o;';echo
> One more "One more "One more LUL and I'm out" and I'm out" and I'm out
```

## Explanation

```
for(
  $o=LUL;                           # Start with output string "LUL".
  ~$argn--;                         # Loop until N is -1.
  $d=~¦                             # Set delimiter to `"` after first
                                    #   iteration.
)
  $o="One more $d$o$d and I'm out"; # Add text with previous output
                                    #   embedded, between delims.

echo$o;                             # Output resulting string.
```

Comment: @devRicher and aross: We have a [Be Nice](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice) policy—please remember to follow it and act with a civil tone, even when disagreeing with someone.

Comment: @Doorknob I'm sure you'll agree that an accusation of cheating is uncalled for. I'm also sure that his downvote (which still stands) should be removed, as I corrected my answer

Answer (score 1):

## Haskell, 51 bytes

Indexes from 1.

```
f 0="LUL";f n="One more \""++f(n-1)++"\" and I'm out"
```

Comment: This seems to incorrectly print the `LUL` in quotes.

Comment: Easy to make index from 0 using `f -1="LUL"`, but I don't see how to remove extra quotes without a bunch of new symbols.

Answer (score 1):

## CJam, <s>51</s> 49 bytes

```
" and I'm out\"""\"One more "li1+_@*"LUL"+1>@@*W<
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/nexus/cjam#@6@kkJiXouCpnquQX1oSo6SkFKPkn5eqkJtflKqglJNpqB3voKXkE@qjpG1o5@CgFW7z/78hAA)

#### Ungolfed:

```
" and I'm out\""   "\"One more " // Push two strings to the stack
     l i 1 +                     // Read a number and add 1
     _ @                         // Copy number and rise '"One more ' to the top
     *                           // Multiply '"One more ' by a number
     "LUL" +                     // Add "LUL"
     1>                          // Chop the first quote
     @@                          // Push the result down
     *                           // Multiply ' and I\'m out"' by a number
     W<                          // Chop the last quote
```

Comment: You can use `W` instead of -1 to save one byte

Comment: Here are some other tricks to shorten this further: https://tio.run/nexus/cjam#@6/kn5eqkJtflKrApZCYl6LgqZ6rkF9aopTgp1@UqZmmpeQT6qOkZWgXbvP/vxEA ... I started by trying to avoid the `\"` by having a single string and adding the `"` to both ends with `\``. Then I needed to split the string which I couldn't do with a length and `/`, because the first part is shorter. So I used a linefeed as a separator and did `N/`. Since we now have both parts in a list, we can easily repeat both of them at once with `f*`. And the `LUL` is inserted at the end with a simple join (`*`).

Comment: That's cool, but it looks more like completely different solution than shortening this further :) That's my first program on CJam, so I didn't know these tricks, thanks. Should I add this solution to the answer?

Comment: @Wolfram It's up to you. I'm happy for you to use it (otherwise I wouldn't have commented ;)).

Comment: @Wolfram a nice first effort! You'll probably benefit a lot by going through Martin's answer

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3, 68 Bytes

`def f(a):return('"One more '*a+'LUL'+(' and I%sm out"'%"'")*a)[1:-1]`

Comment: This gives incorrect output. Did you mean `*a` instead of `*5`?

Comment: Yes I did, thanks, I hadn't realised I'd put that

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby, 70 bytes

```
def l x,t="LUL";x.times{t='"One more %s and I\'m out"'%t};t[1..~1];end
```

Simply loops for the amount it's given, surrounding the last string via a format string each time.

Index starts at one.

Answer (score 1):

### Mathematica, <s>65</s> 63 Bytes

```
Nest["\"One more "<>#<>" and I'm out\""&,"LUL",#]~StringTrim~_&
```

Two bytes off by noticing the challenge allows 1-indexing.

Answer (score 1):

### Groovy, 54 bytes

```groovy
{x->('"One more '*x+'LUL'+' and I\'m out\"'*x)[1..-2]}
```

Pretty straightforward, same as the python answer but 2 bytes shorter. It is also 1-indexed.

[Try it Online!](https://tio.run/#5e255)

Answer (score 1):

## PHP

Hello, i found so far two ways for doing this.

The replacement way 1-indexed **(121 bytes)**.

```
function f($x){$v='One more LUL and i\'m out';$t=$v;for($i=1;$i<=$x;$t=str_replace('LUL','"'.$t.'"',$v),$i++);return $t;}
```

The recursive way **(86 bytes)**.

```
function r($n){$v=($n==0)?'LUL':'"'.r($n-1).'"';return'One more '.$v.' and i\'m out';}
```

Comment: In php, programs are almost always shorter than functions.

Answer (score 1):

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 91 bytes

```
set g [set f "One more LUL and I'm out"]
time {regsub -all LUL $f "\"$g\"" f} $argv
puts $f
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0nO@f@/OLVEIV0hGkSlKSj556Uq5OYXpSr4hPooJOalKHiq5yrkl5YoxXKVZOamKlQXpaYXlyYp6Cbm5IDVqAA1xSippMcoKSmk1SqoJBall3EVlJYUA2X@//9vDAA)

Comment: Is `set n ...` a valid passing of value in shell script golfing?

Comment: @JonathanFrech Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

## C++, 80 + 16 = 96 bytes

```c++
std::string L(int c){return"One more "+(c?'"'+L(--c)+'"':"LUL")+" and I'm out";}
```

`#include<string>` - +16

Ungolfed:

```c++
std::string LUL(int count) {
    return "One more " + (count? ('"' + LUL(--count) + '"') : "LUL") + " and I'm out";
}
```

Calls itself recursively and uses string addition. Pretty straight forward. I mean what else can I say? Even the ungolfed version is essentially a one liner.

[Try it online!](http://cpp.sh/4mcgj)

Answer (score 1):

## Common Lisp, <s>90</s> <s>89</s> <s>108</s> <s>105</s> 103 bytes

```
(set's"One more LUL and I'm out")(dotimes(n(read)(princ s))(set's(format()"One more ~a and I'm out"s)))
```

#### Other solution (91 bytes)

Using [Winny's](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/107323/one-more-lul-and-im-out/107440#107440) solution in Racket (my is not exact copy)

```
(defun l(n)(if(< n 0)'LUL(format()"One more ~:[~a~;\"~a\"~] and I'm out"(> n 0)(l(1- n)))))
```

usage:

```
(format t"~a"(l 2))
```

Ideas for improvement are welcomed.

Answer (score 1):

## [Cheddar](http://cheddar.vihan.org/), 71 bytes

```
i->('One more "'*i).slice(0,-1)+'LUL '+('and I\'m out" '*i).slice(0,-2)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/cheddar#K0ssUkiz/Z@pa6eh7p@XqpCbX5SqoKSulampV5yTmZyqYaCja6ipre4T6qOgrq2hnpiXouAZo56rkF9aoqSAqs5I839BUWZeiUaahqmm5n8A)

Comment: Maybe try recursion with `_ f ->` syntax which may save some bytes

Comment: Uhh, I'm not really familiar with how that syntax works, and I can't find it or any examples in the docs.

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 39 bytes

First Jelly submission! Can probably slice off a few by encoding the strings, but I couldn't get it working with the spaces yet.

```
“"One more ”;;“ and I'm out"”
“LUL”Ç¡ḊṖ
```

A 0-indexed version needs an additional `Ç` after the `Ç¡`.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@/@oYY6Sf16qQm5@UarCo4a51tZAEYXEvBQFT/VchfzSEiWgIBdQzCfUB8g63H5o4eH2hzu6Hu6c9v@/6f///wE)

**Explanation** will follow soon!

Answer (score 1):

## Haskell - 73 bytes

```
n!s=[1..n]>>s
f n=init(n!"One more \"")++" LUL"++tail(n!"\" and I'm out")
```

I wonder if there something I could use besides init and tail to save a few bytes.

[Try it here!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P0@x2DbaUE8vL9bOrpgrTSHPNjMvs0QjT1HJPy9VITe/KFUhRklJU1tbScEn1EdJW7skMTMHJB2jpJCYl6LgqZ6rkF9aoqT5/z8A)

Comment: There is an extra space in `" LUL"` which should be removed.

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 55 + 1 (-p) = 56 bytes

```perl
$_='"One more 'x++$_.LUL.' and I\'m out"'x$_;s/^.|.$//g
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18l3lZdyT8vVSE3vyhVQb1CW1slXs8n1EdPXSExL0XBM0Y9VyG/tERJvUIl3rpYP06vRk9FXz/9/3/jf/kFJZn5ecX/dQsA)

Comment: Nice approach! Couldn't come up with an alternative, but a little rearrangement can save you 6 bytes (plus dropping the +1 for `-p`): [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18l3lbdPy9VITe/KFVBSb1CW1slXk9dSSExL0XBM0Y9VyG/tES9QiXeuthaScnaJ9Tn/38DLkMuIy7zf/kFJZn5ecX/dQtyAA "Perl 5 – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 27 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
âΔ▓♥CPM9C"4█é¢┐╥äΔ↔╖◄b)►┤≤▐
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=83ffb20343504d39432234db829bbfd284ff1db711622910b4f3de&i=0%0A1%0A2%0A3&a=1&m=2)

This is a recursive program that decrements the input on each call.

I discovered a bug in stax writing this program.  I'll fix the bug sooner or later, but I won't incorporate it into this solution, as it seems unsporting to me.

Answer (score 1):

### Microsoft Excel, 69

Cells:

- `A1` - input
- `A2` - `One more "`
- `A3` - `" and I'm out`
- `A4` - `""` (Otherwise I'd have to escape them)
- Wherever - `=SUBSTITUTE(REPT(A2,A1)&REPT(A3,A1),A4,"LUL"`

Answer (score 1):

## [International Esoteric Phonetic Language](https://esolangs.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Esoteric_Language), 80 bytes

```
<f>/qubʌɔ|a|"\""u1z<f>"\""uɔ|b||a|ʍu|b|ɖbuʈ\"LUL"w" and I'm out""One more "ɪ<f>""o
```

Recursive implementation that decrements the input number when recursing.

### Explanation:

```
<f>/qubʌɔ|a|"\""u1z<f>"\""uɔ|b||a|ʍu|b|ɖbuʈ\"LUL"w" and I'm out""One more "ɪ<f>""o
<f>/                                                                              (fun def)
    qu                                                                            (one more)
      bʌɔ|a|                                                                      (if index == 0, continue, else jump to else)
           "\""u                                                                  (quote)
                1z                                                                (decrement index)
                  <f>                                                             (recurse)
                     "\""u                                                        (quote)
                          ɔ|b|                                                    (skip to end)
                              |a|                                                 (else)
                                 ʍu                                               (LUL)
                                   |b|                                            (end)
                                      ɖbuʈ\                                       (and i'm out)
                                           "LUL"w                                 (wegister going wwww LUL)
                                                 " and I'm out""One more "        (strings)
                                                                          ɪ<f>    (input and call)
                                                                              ""o (print newline)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 27 bytes

```
!¡σ"LUL"s₁₁
¨Ønø LULÄdİ'møo
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/X/HQwvPNSj6hPkrFj5oagYjr0IrDM/IO71AAih1uSTmyQT338I78////mwMA)

Does infinite replacement of LUL and indexes into it.

1-indexed.

Answer (score 1):

## YASEPL, 161 bytes

```
=a'(=s)"One more "=u)apostrophe=m)" and I"ſuſ"m out"=x)"LUL"=n=q$34»!a@!sſq!-!m)qſ" and I"ſuſ"m out"=x)"One more LUL"ſ" and I"ſuſ"m out"`1!b;s,a~#x;m,a<
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org/), 57 bytes

```
{substr "\"One more "x$_~"LUL"~" and I'm out\""x$_,1,*-1}
```

Slightly more interesting, but 58 bytes:

```
{join "LUL",("One more "," and I'm out"Xxx$_)».join('"')}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Clojure, 84 bytes

```
#(nth(iterate(fn[s](str"One more \""s"\" and I'm out"))"One more LUL and I'm out")%)
```

Argh why isn't the first `LUL` in quotes? :( Almost correct in 63 bytes:

```
#(nth(iterate(fn[s](str"One more \""s"\" and I'm out"))"LUL")%)
```

Answer (score 0):

## GameMaker Language, 106 bytes

1-indexed

```
s='LUL'for(a=0,a<argument0;a++)s='"One more '+s+" and I'm out\""return string_copy(s,2,string_length(s)-2)
```

Answer (score 0):

## Clojure, 90 bytes

```clj
(fn c[n](if(= n -1)"LUL"(let[q(if(> n 0) \")](str"One more "q(c(dec n))q" and I'm out"))))
```

Written and golfed on my phone on a soft keyboard using the "Clojure REPL" app. That was sure a treat.

Explicitly recursive solution. Inserts the results of recursing into the "template string".

Pregolfed:

```clj
(defn lul [n]
  (if (= n -1)
    "LUL"
    (let [quote? (if (> n 0) \")]
      (str "One more "
            quote? (lul (dec n)) quote?
           " and I'm out" ))))
```

Answer (score 0):

## Octave, <s>72</s> 70 bytes

```
@(n)[{'"One more '}{o=!(1:n)+1} "LUL " {"and I'm out\" "}{o}](2:end-2)
```

1 based index

[Try It Online!](https://tio.run/#FsWhh)

Answer (score 0):

## PowerShell, 88 bytes

```
for($d=($s="One more LUL and I'm out");$i++-lt$args[0]){$d=$d.Replace("LUL","`"$s`"")}$d
```

Answer (score 0):

### Batch, 95 bytes

```
@set s=LUL
@for /l %%i in (0,1,%1)do @call set s="One more %%s%% and I'm out"
@echo %s:~1,-1%
```

0-indexed, because that means it works even if you forget to pass a parameter. (The 1-indexed version would just print `U` in that case, which looks silly.)

Answer (score 0):

## C#, <s>102</s> 90 bytes

<s>`string l(string s,int n){return n<0?s.Substring(1,s.Length-2):l($"\"One more {s} and I'm out\"",--n);}`</s>

Recursive, call with <s>`l("LUL",7);`</s>

**EDIT**

Thank you for pointing out that it is illegal to pass input not specified in the challenge. Here is the fixed version that only takes an integer `N`:

```
string l(int N){return N<0?"":$"One more \"{l(--N)}\" and I'm out".Replace("\"\"","LUL");}
```

Comment: You can't assume that this string is passed as input. [It's a standard loophole](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/1789/32014), which is forbidden by default. - @Zgarb in the deleted Java 7 answer

Comment: Sorry I am new to this. Do I have to add the call to the total bytes? Or find another solution that does only assume an `int N` as input?

Comment: You need to find another solution that only assumes the integer

Comment: Another option is to use C#'s optional arguments thing, so `string l(int n,string s="LUL")` works as well. But your new solution is now shorter anyways, so it might be better to just leave it as is! Unless someone else with more C# knowledge knows how to golf it further, of course.

Answer (score 0):

## Racket, <s>88</s> 87 bytes

```rkt
(define(f n)(format"One more ~a and I'm out"(if(= n 0)'LUL(format"\"~a\""(f(- n 1))))))
```

### Ungolfed

```rkt
(define (f n)
  (format "One more ~a and I'm out"
          (if (= n 0)
              'LUL
              (format "\"~a\"" (f (- n 1))))))
```

### Unit tests

```rkt
(module+ test
  (require rackunit)
  (check-equal? (f 0) "One more LUL and I'm out")
  (check-equal? (f 1) "One more \"One more LUL and I'm out\" and I'm out")
  (check-equal? (f 2) "One more \"One more \"One more LUL and I'm out\" and I'm out\" and I'm out")
  (check-equal? (f 7) "One more \"One more \"One more \"One more \"One more \"One more \"One more \"One more LUL and I'm out\" and I'm out\" and I'm out\" and I'm out\" and I'm out\" and I'm out\" and I'm out\" and I'm out"))
```

Comment: I tried it on my PC and it seems your code outputs additional `"` on beggining and end. Also for n>=1 output should be `One more "One more LUL and I'm out" and I'm out` without backslash before `"` etc. It is possible that I have some old version of `Racket` but please look into it. Also - you can save one byte with `'LUL` instead of `"LUL"`

Comment: @PrzemysławP In the Racket string `"a\"b\"c"`, typing it into the repl will result the same as what you typed, you want to do `(displayln "a\"b\"c")` which outputs just `a"b"c`. Nice catch on the -1 byte, thanks!

Comment: So your function outputs string that is appropriate for other function to read and output what is needed. I doesn't output what is needed on its own. But probably you know better than me what is allowed - I may try to use this somewhere.

Comment: @PrzemysławP Could you clarify what isn't correct in this answer? I have no clue what you're going on about.

Comment: I am sorry for confusion. What I think may be incorrect is that output contains escape characters and quotes. To get rid of them you need to use other function on it (`displayln` if I understand you correctly). However it is possible that it is allowed, hence my "But probably you know better than me what is allowed(...)". To put it straight: when I write to REPL function definition and function call it displays different thing than what is defined in "Sample Input/Output" section in question.

Answer (score 0):

## Scala, 63 bytes

```
(n:Int)=>("One more \""*n init)+"LUL"+("\" and I'm out"*n tail)
```

1-indexed

Answer (score 0):

## C++, 183 bytes

Simply input N times you want 'One more LUL' nested.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#define s string
using namespace std;main(){int N;cin>>N;s a="LUL";s b="One more \"";s c="\"and I'm out";for(int i=0;i<N;i++){a=b+a+c;}cout<<a;}
```

[Try Me Online!](http://cpp.sh/2hkm)

Comment: doesn't work. 1 should output "one more LUL and I'm out" with no quotes

Answer (score 0):

## C++14, 90 bytes

As unnamed lambda modifying its input. Requires `s` to be `std::string` or alike.

```cpp
[](auto&s,int i){s="LUL",++i;for(char c=0;i--;s="One more "+(c+s+c)+" and I'm out",c=34);}
```

Ungolfed and usage:

```cpp
#include<string>
#include<iostream>

auto f=
[](auto&s,int i){
 s="LUL",++i;        //set basic LUL
 for(
  char c=0;          //first string concat without quotes
  i--;               
  s="One more "+(c+s+c)+" and I'm out", //string concat
  c=34                                  //set c to "
 );
}
;

int main(){
 std::string s;
 f(s,0);
 std::cout << s << std::endl;
 f(s,1);
 std::cout << s << std::endl;
 f(s,2);
 std::cout << s << std::endl;
 f(s,3);
 std::cout << s << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: does this output null bytes?

Comment: @DestructibleWatermelon no, it just works. I guess adding the null-char is just ignored.

Comment: how did you check exactly?

Comment: By running and checking the output.

Answer (score 0):

## Objective-C, 218

```
#define p NSString stringWithFormat
-(NSString *)f:(int)a{NSString *o=@"One more ",*k=@" and I'm out",*i=[p:@"%@LUL%@",o,k],*s=@"";for(int j=-a;a-->j+1;s=[p:@"%@\"%@",s,a>0?o:a<0?k:i]);return [s substringFromIndex:1];}
```

Not the most beautiful language to golf in, but I had fun

Answer (score 0):

### [QBIC](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B0R1Jgqp8Gg4cVJCZkRkdEthZDQ), 72 bytes

```
:[a|X=X+@One more `+chr$(34)┘Z=Z+chr$(34)+@ and I'm out`]Z=X+A+@LUL`+B+Z
```

The `chr$(34)` for the quotes is particularly costly, I need to fix a bug in the interpreter to make them work inside a string literal...

Sample output:

```
Command line: 0
One more LUL and I'm out

Command line: 3
One more "One more "One more "One more LUL and I'm out" and I'm out" and I'm out" and I'm out
```

Answer (score 0):

## [dc](https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/dc-1.05/html_mono/dc.html), 82 bytes

```
?dsasw[[LUL ]P]se[34dP]sr[lalw>r[One more ]nlad1-dsar1=e0<y[and I'm out]nP32P]dsyx
```

Might as well add an answer in `dc`. This is 1-indexed.

["Calculate" it on the Internet!](https://tio.run/nexus/dc#@2@fUpxYXB4d7RPqoxAbEFucGm1skgKki6JzEnPK7Yqi/fNSFXLzi1IVYvNyElMMdYHqiwxtUw1sKqMT81IUPNVzFfJLS2LzAoyNAmJTiisr/v83@ZqXr5ucmJyRCgA)

Answer (score 0):

## Python, 78 bytes

```
f=lambda n:'One more "'*(n-1)+"One more LUL and I'm out"+'" and I\'m out'*(n-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

## k, 58 bytes

Indexing starts at `0`. This is a recursive function.

```
`0:`c${"One more ",$[x;34,o[x-1],34;"LUL"]," and I'm out"}
```

[Try it online.](http://johnearnest.github.io/ok/?run=%600%3A%60c%24%7B%22One%20more%20%22%2C%24%5Bx%3B34%2Co%5Bx-1%5D%2C34%3B%22LUL%22%5D%2C%22%20and%20I%27m%20out%22%7D2%3B)

Answer (score 0):

## [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), 44 bytes

```
~"LUL"\{'"One more 
 and I\'m out"'n/*}*(;);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPn/v07JJ9RHKaZaXck/L1UhN78oVYFLITEvRcEzRj1XIb@0REk9T1@rVkvDWtP6/38LAA)

1-indexed.

Explanation:

```
~"LUL"\{'"One more \n and I\'m out"'n/*}*(;); ("\n" is a newline)
~                                             Eval (input is the only stack element on program start)
 "LUL"                                        Push "LUL"
      \                                       Swap
       {'"One more \n and I\'m out"'n/*}      Push block:
        '"One more \n and I\'m out"'            Push "\"One more \n and I'm out\""
                                    n           Push n (default: newline)
                                     /          Split
                                      *         Join
                                        *     Repeat block
                                         (    Pop first element and push to stack
                                          ;   Pop
                                           )  Pop last element and push to stack
                                            ; Pop
```

Answer (score 0):

## [SOGL V0.12](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL), 27 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL/blob/master/chartable.md)

```
LUL”.I{" ž-┌πēj░ō|≥π┘⁴‘⁾}jk
```

[Try it Here!](https://dzaima.github.io/SOGLOnline/?code=TFVMJXUyMDFELkklN0IlMjIlMjAldTAxN0UtJXUyNTBDJXUwM0MwJXUwMTEzaiV1MjU5MSV1MDE0RCU3QyV1MjI2NSV1MDNDMCV1MjUxOCV1MjA3NCV1MjAxOCV1MjA3RSU3RGpr,inputs=MQ__)

Answer (score 0):

## [FEU](https://github.com/TryItOnline/feu), <s>107</s> 97 bytes

```
Ep/v
a/One more LUL and I'm out
EP/v
u/a
/a/g
Ep/v
s/LUL/"One more LUL and I'm out"
EP/v
end
Ep/v
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0st/f/ftUC/jCtR3z8vVSE3vyhVwSfURyExL0XBUz1XIb@0hMs1AChfqp/IpZ@on84FVl2sD1Skr4RLixJET2peClj5//8GAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 33 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
`O Ú {?Q²¬qßUÉ:`lª`u} d I'm t
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=YE%2baINqQIHs/UbKscd9VyTpgbKpgdX0ghGQgSSdtIIx0&input=Nw)

Answer (score 0):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), <s>34</s> 33 bytes

```
`"λŀ λƈ `*‛⇧Ṫ⇧+` λ¬ I'm λ₅"`?*+ḢṪ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJBIiwiIiwiYFwizrvFgCDOu8aIIGAq4oCb4oen4bmq4oenK2AgzrvCrCBJJ20gzrvigoVcImA/KivhuKLhuaoiLCIiLCIxXG4yXG4zIl0=)

-1 thx to @steffan

Comment: `\`LUL\`` => `‛⇧Ṫ⇧`

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 34 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
ʋLULs{‘"One Ḍḋ % and I'm out"‘Œ}ḣṫ
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faMGCpaUlaboWNw1OdfuE-hRXP2qYoeSfl6rwcEfPwx3dCqoKiXkpCp7quQr5pSVKQMmjk2of7lj8cOfqJcVJycVQ3QsWGkMYAA)

##### Explanation

```python
ʋLULs{‘...‘Œ}ḣṫ  # Implicit input
ʋLUL             # Push the string "LUL"
    s            # Swap so the input is back on top
     {      }    # Repeat input number of times:
      ‘...‘      # Push compressed template string
                 # `"One more % and I'm out"`
           Œ     # Replace the "%" with the
                 # next item on the stack
             ḣṫ  # Remove the first and last characters
                 # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 0):

## TypeScript's type system, <s>100</s> 77 bytes

```typescript
type F<N>=`One more ${N extends[1,...infer K]?`"${F<K>}"`:"LUL"} and I'm out`
```

[Try it at the TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgPAOQHwF4AGB5AdtAtgewCdoASAbwSggA9gIsATAZwG0BGAGgDoeBLLAGYRCUANIBdAPxoAROXiikAXxloAXDIAyAVU0ylUAIaMoASQDkuKPgCuwNACgHoSFAAqEJsAAMUFLDgWcSQHAHpQqEiAPUlncGgPLzY-APZgsIjo2JcEz2AAJhT4dg42dPDIqBi410TgAGYiwM4W8syq7Pj3PIAWJpKW0rbK6qA)

This is a generic type `F<N>` where N is a unary number represented by a tuple type of 1s.

This is not tail recursive, so it only works for N < 50. Here's a tail recursive version which works for N < 1000:

## TypeScript's type system, 106 bytes

```typescript
// @ts-ignore
type F<N,O="LUL",W="">=N extends[1,...infer K]?F<K,`One more ${W}${O}${W} and I'm out`,'"'>:O
```

[Try it at the TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEAEBcGcFoEsDmA7A9gJwKYChIE8AHTUAMQB4A5AGgHkBeAIgBkBVJhqgdUYYD46KoTAA9ImZABNoAbQCMVAHRL4yAGaZ0oANIBdAPzktVAAY1kxALYZiAEgDenAL72azh49ABDSaACSAcgtQVABXSGMqfwZ-XgAuGmxcQmIAFUxoSAAGUDpSMmkdXmwQUFKAPT0kolA0jNkcvLlC4rByyvxq2sgAJgbyOSpZZpK2qtT0yABmPvz5OeHW0AqxmomAFhmBucGF0qXK7CA)