# Russian Nesting Quine

Tags: code-golf, quine, source-layout

A Russian nesting doll, more commonly known as a [Matryoshka doll](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matryoshka_doll), is a doll which contains a smaller version of itself, <sup>which then contains another smaller version of itself, <sup>which contains a smaller version of itself,  <sup>which contains a smaller version of itself, <sup>which contains a smaller version of itself...</sup></sup></sup></sup> - until finally, the last one is empty.

Today your goal is to emulate this Russian tradition by writing a program or function that, when it contains itself N times, will print itself containing N-1 copies of itself times.

For example, the doll program `abcd` will have the N=3 program `abababcdcdcd`, which will print the N=2 program `ababcdcd`, which prints the original N=1 program `abcd`, which finally prints N=0, which is empty. This should theoretically work for any reasonable value of N.

Rules:

- Here is a [TIO program](https://tio.run/##PY0xDoMwDEX3nMJbh0BP4Hrv0gtYGQgYgVCTioSinj51QK0ly9Z737JfuzmMW7@UB9zAahkiKg1T4wwyt2TRIaMjbtGSDnKopiI0bAA0QnxVY0/olFGNUZWHOnhte4q2ZvBHdbf/utY3eO6kl2hZkatHxpV7eG0ZgsiQIEfwAl0AeUuA7hm3kCGO4D9ZEsQ8ybrPSSBPc4IhSgqXDHtcl9L5fvgC) to help generate doll programs based on your program
- [Standard Quine Rules apply](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4877/76162)
- [Standard Loopholes apply](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1061/76162)
- 'Contains' means directly in the center of the previous version, so your solution must have a positive even number of bytes. A program of length 10 will have a copy of the original inserted after the fifth byte, then another after the tenth byte etc.
- A single trailing whitespace is allowed in the output
- As this is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), your goal is to make your N=1 program as short as possible.
- An explanation of your code would be appreciated

Comment: [Sandbox post](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14701/76162) (deleted)

Comment: For what `N` is the code size measured?

Comment: @flawr N=1.....

Comment: `N=0, which is empty` it HAS to be empty, or can be a single character?

Comment: @Rod *Has* to be empty. 0 copies of a program is a blank string

Comment: [Related: One More Program and I'm Out!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/143921/one-more-program-and-im-out)

Comment: Is even character count, odd or fractional byte count OK?

Comment: @noodleman hmm, tough question. i would say that as long as the output encoding matches the program encoding (as should be mandatory for quines), and that the program can be split evenly, e.g. 3 bytes split into 1.5+1.5 bytes

Answer (score 10):

## [Underload](https://github.com/catseye/stringie), 4 bytes

N=1: [Try it online.](https://tio.run/##K81LSS3KyU9M@f9fQUMz@P9/AA)

```
 ()S
```

N=2: [Try it online.](https://tio.run/##K81LSS3KyU9M@f9fQUNBQzNYM/j/fwA)

```
 ( ()S)S
```

N=3: [Try it online.](https://tio.run/##K81LSS3KyU9M@f9fQQMENYNB8P9/AA)

```
 ( ( ()S)S)S
```

**Explanation:**

Self-explanatory, but I add it anyway.

- `(...)S` prints anything between the parenthesis to STDOUT
- The space before it is a no-op to make the byte-count even and comply to the rules of the challenge.

Answer (score 10):

## JavaScript, <s>36</s> 32 bytes

Takes advantage of the fact that `Function.prototype.toString()` takes no arguments and will therefore ignore any that are passed to it.

Partly inspired by [user202729's solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/154637/58974).

```js
f=_=>f.toString( ).slice(14,-16)
```

---

### Try it

```js
o.innerHTML=["<span>Five</span>",(f=_=>f.toString(f=_=>f.toString(f=_=>f.toString(f=_=>f.toString(f=_=>f.toString( ).slice(14,-16) ).slice(14,-16) ).slice(14,-16) ).slice(14,-16) ).slice(14,-16))(),"<span>Four</span>",(f=_=>f.toString(f=_=>f.toString(f=_=>f.toString(f=_=>f.toString( ).slice(14,-16) ).slice(14,-16) ).slice(14,-16) ).slice(14,-16))(),"<span>Three</span>",(f=_=>f.toString(f=_=>f.toString(f=_=>f.toString( ).slice(14,-16) ).slice(14,-16) ).slice(14,-16))(),"<span>Two</span>",(f=_=>f.toString(f=_=>f.toString( ).slice(14,-16) ).slice(14,-16))(),"<span>One</span>",(f=_=>f.toString( ).slice(14,-16))(),"<span>Thunderbirds Are Go!</span>"].join`\n`
```

```css
span{font-weight:bold;font-size:16px;line-height:1.5em;text-transform:uppercase;}span:last-child{font-size:8px;}
```

```html
<pre id=o></pre>
```

Answer (score 7):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 46 bytes

Full program. So `console.log` is necessary.

Use an idea from [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/154642/69850) to save some bytes.

```javascript
l=console.log;   g=_=>{};l((''+g).slice(4,-1))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/f8/xzY5P684PydVLyc/3VpBQSHdNt7WrrrWOkdDQ11dO11TrzgnMzlVw0RH11BT8/9/AA) [Try it online twice!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/f8/xzY5P684PydVLyc/3VpBQSHdNt7WrhqHcK11joaGurp2uqZecU5mcqqGiY6uoaYmDuH//wE) [Try it online, three times!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/f8/xzY5P684PydVLyc/3VpBQSHdNt7Wrpo04VrrHA0NdXXtdE294pzM5FQNEx1dQ01N0oT//wcA)

---

My approach is similar to that used in Kevin Cruijssen's [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/154636/69850), find a nestable structure (a function in this case).

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 16 bytes

```
Ṿḣ-9Ḋð}“““““““““
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hzn0PdyzWtXy4o@vwhtpHDXNwof//AQ)

Doubled: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hzn0PdyzWtXy4o@vwhtpHDXMwBEhF//8DAA)

Tripled: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hzn0PdyzWtXy4o@vwhtpHDXMIC1AL/f8PAA)

---

Jelly doesn't have any nestable structure, but its string literals are auto-terminated.

```
Ṿḣ-9Ḋ    First chain. (monadic)
Ṿ        UneṾal. (to string)
 ḣ-9     Take the ḣead, ends at the -9'th character.
    Ḋ    Ḋequeue, remove the first character.

     ð             Terminate the first chain, start a new one.
      }            Convert the last monadic chain to a dyadic one.
       “““““““““   String literal.
                   This matches the pattern <dyad> <nilad>, so applies
                   the the corresponding rules. This way a link can take data
                   to the right of it.
```

---

Will try different approaches to see if they can be shorter.

Answer (score 4):

## [DipDup](https://github.com/AlephAlpha/DipDup), 2 bytes

```
[]
```

It pushes the list onto the stack, and prints it without the outmost brackets.

N = 1: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZVRNj9owEL3nV0wjJBJRuPWClr0gKlVqVVR6i9KsN5hibWJbjilB6n@nM@N8LeVAxm/emy9PchbNm6yq@13V1jgPP2XrV3vhGum2pn5VWnjjmtUPKY77KDoKL5DiatjAFrZn4eAv7GDXWhdF/mYlm@jMiJRHkdKNF7qUcDiba1Bez9LJCPDXEJZsoUxJUeYTcAeSwDiLYbEImCQrzuOB9VU1HjnJYpHCCkqjS@G/Ccu@SWYq/TGzQ6zZO1miHoUYZ8bYvvCmOLBJioHbpXqghLZ7MqzXnGvPyUZ4Qy0@zZ6hEV41pxskL9r4XSXrF@wvj9MUG1tQy0R6lf4qpYakpOHOs3namzmafdY0pOVhD2m5nAHeQC30bWwl3N3Bi/INfUG5XAcAh3VSrYNPBNHolA/E9UjoIbypnJUDhDdv7ECF5XOohMCkZWpBd9l2G/L5omnsA7mLIf@Iqh8jP9FF1NHRL0UiKWg6cWxh/mtOrqOy7@EiwJcH@APD1jzAa4ZpIUa8QEQdQ339vPk5ra@b@KlSFlfxZKpjhRvFxz5QiDBV85QY3AANazUKmDIZMPZFSs5HdjfXG/83VHQwB20LDaouE9VlUDE/mB0QRdaMVLKTYqSim0Yy@PnwfwV4PXiCNu1jOtlthVP6d7hpshhX2l7ojSpFIyFr8SuStB8hjlN4Woa3M1ByMCd@C7M2pxD8JZhxn7hQ5CgIls4ZB7Gl71Y4xFFUC6WpgC/fIUnDCa9Se@lE6TGJvd@z/B8)

N = 2: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZVRNj9owEL3nV0wjJBJRuPWClr0gKlVqVVR6i9KsN5hibWJbjilB6n@nM@N8LeVAxm/emy9PchbNm6yq@13V1jgPP2XrV3vhGum2pn5VWnjjmtUPKY77KDoKL5DiatjAFrZn4eAv7GDXWhdF/mYlm@jMiJRHkdKNF7qUcDiba1Bez9LJCPDXEJZsoUxJUeYTcAeSwDiLYbEImCQrzuOB9VU1HjnJYpHCCkqjS@G/Ccu@SWYq/TGzQ6zZO1miHoUYZ8bYvvCmOLBJioHbpXqghLZ7MqzXnGvPyUZ4Qy0@zZ6hEV41pxskL9r4XSXrF@wvj9MUG1tQy0R6lf4qpYakpOHOs3namzmafdY0pOVhD2m5nAHeQC30bWwl3N3Bi/INfUG5XAcAh3VSrYNPBNHolA/E9UjoIbypnJUDhDdv7ECF5XOohMCkZWpBd9l2G/L5omnsA7mLIf@Iqh8jP9FF1NHRL0UiKWg6cWxh/mtOrqOy7@EiwJcH@APD1jzAa4ZpIUa8QEQdQ339vPk5ra@b@KlSFlfxZKpjhRvFxz5QiDBV85QY3AANazUKmDIZMPZFSs5HdjfXG/83VHQwB20LDaouE9VlUDE/mB0QRdaMVLKTYqSim0Yy@PnwfwV4PXiCNu1jOtlthVP6d7hpshhX2l7ojSpFIyFr8SuStB8hjlN4Woa3M1ByMCd@C7M2pxD8JZhxn7hQ5CgIls4ZB7Gl71Y4xFFUC6WpgC/fIUnDCa9Se@lE6TGJvd@zLM//AQ)

N = 3: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZVRNj9owEL3nV0wjJBJRuPWClr0gKlVqVVR6i9KsN5hibWJbjilB6n@nM@N8LeVAxm/emy9PchbNm6yq@13V1jgPP2XrV3vhGum2pn5VWnjjmtUPKY77KDoKL5DiatjAFrZn4eAv7GDXWhdF/mYlm@jMiJRHkdKNF7qUcDiba1Bez9LJCPDXEJZsoUxJUeYTcAeSwDiLYbEImCQrzuOB9VU1HjnJYpHCCkqjS@G/Ccu@SWYq/TGzQ6zZO1miHoUYZ8bYvvCmOLBJioHbpXqghLZ7MqzXnGvPyUZ4Qy0@zZ6hEV41pxskL9r4XSXrF@wvj9MUG1tQy0R6lf4qpYakpOHOs3namzmafdY0pOVhD2m5nAHeQC30bWwl3N3Bi/INfUG5XAcAh3VSrYNPBNHolA/E9UjoIbypnJUDhDdv7ECF5XOohMCkZWpBd9l2G/L5omnsA7mLIf@Iqh8jP9FF1NHRL0UiKWg6cWxh/mtOrqOy7@EiwJcH@APD1jzAa4ZpIUa8QEQdQ339vPk5ra@b@KlSFlfxZKpjhRvFxz5QiDBV85QY3AANazUKmDIZMPZFSs5HdjfXG/83VHQwB20LDaouE9VlUDE/mB0QRdaMVLKTYqSim0Yy@PnwfwV4PXiCNu1jOtlthVP6d7hpshhX2l7ojSpFIyFr8SuStB8hjlN4Woa3M1ByMCd@C7M2pxD8JZhxn7hQ5CgIls4ZB7Gl71Y4xFFUC6WpgC/fIUnDCa9Se@lE6TGJvd@zLMvz/B8)

Answer (score 3):

## [dc](https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/dc-1.05/html_mono/dc.html), 4 bytes

```
 []p
```

Similar to some other answers, since strings in `dc` have start (`[`) and end (`]`) delimiters (that is, `"` doesn't perform both duties, etc.), they're nestable without any real effort. `p` to print.

N=1: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0n@/18hOrbg/38A)

N=2: [Try it nested!](https://tio.run/##S0n@/18hWiE6tiC24P9/AA)

N=3: [Try it nesteder!](https://tio.run/##S0n@/18hGgRjC0Dw/38A)

Answer (score 2):

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 12 bytes

```
puts {}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0nO@f@/oLSkWKEamaxVAAFk8v9/AA)

It's just another language that also has this.